# What is the best way to store accelerometer information?

Tags: android, sql, storage

First sorry if this is not the correct exchange site (I thought possibly code review but since I don't have any 'code' to review I thought not).

What would be the best practices in storing the following data.

I have an application which records sensor data with the follow information:

- Name
- Date
- Notes
- ArrayList < Accelerometer Data >

  - X
  - Y
  - Z
  - Timestamp

I will also be collecting the MAGNETOMETER sensor data but for now accelerometer data is enough.

My current idea is to use an SQL Table with the following columns

```
------------------------------   
|Name | Date | Notes | Values|
------------------------------
```

With values being a serialised list of `Accelerometer data`. Although it would also be nice for the values to be in a separate table, almost like a table within a table. Although I believe having a variable number of tables in a database is bad practice is this so? Is there a better way to store this data?

-- Edit --

- This data does need to be persisted on the disk until it is deleted
  by user choice.
- It should ideally be protected from data corruption
- The system will not need to update / edit it once it has been saved.
- It will at some point in the future be able to be accessed so it can
  be uploaded.
- Looking to the future the sensor values data will need to be encrypted.

Comment: Many factors are not mentioned in your question. Does the data need to be persisted over time? Or is it only needed  for immediate, one-time use. Are here many users accessing it simultaneously/concurrently? does it need to be persisted in a transactional way (with other data)? If persisted, does it need to be protected from inadvertent data corruption ? Once a data point is initially created, does the system have (or need) the capability to modify or update it?  etc. etc. Depending on answers, your best option may NOT be a database.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesBretana i've updated the question sorry I should have put more information in from the start!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first having multiple `tables` in a `database` is kinda the normal practice for storing datas. just imagine this site, *it has a table for the user, a table for the comments, a table for the questions, a table for the answers, a table for up-down votes, .....*

Now the *best practice* is mostly opinion based, so I will just tell you about the SQLite option.

A solution might be to create two `tables`: one for the basic stuffs and another one for all the list of values.

Something like two classes:

```
public class genericDatas{
    private UUID id;    
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private String notes;
    //getter, setter, constructor,...
}

public class accelerometerValues{
    private UUID id;
    private UUID GenericValueIdREF;
    //...
    //getter, setter, constructor,...
}
```

Now save all datas you need and retrieve them with a Select with a Join or with two select or any ways you like more. [Here is the guide on how to use SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: You say that having multiple tables is okay but is it okay to have a variable amount of tables I was lead to believe that was not good. Also thats is how I am currently saving the data within the code its self, that is another option I have considered is to just save the data as serialised objects, is that what you were getting at? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @jackdh that is not a problem also, you can even save datas as serialized objects but for querying and accessing them later is better to use normal object within sqlite.